# Field Calculator - use a string field to determine how a calculation is applied to a numeric field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, arcgis-10.5

I have a String field ('Prefix') and a Double field ('Result'). I am trying to group data by a specific range, <0.002, 0.002 to 0.07, >0.07, however some values have a '<' or '>' prefix contained in the String field. This causes me issues where i have the value 0.07 in one cell and the value 0.07 in another cell with the prefix '<', which represent 0.07 and <0.07 respectively.

What I would like to do is create a new Double attribute called 'Result_Edit'(easy enough) and use Field Calculator to look for all cases where the 'Prefix' field (String) has a '<' or '>' and the 'Result' is 0.002 or 0.07, and either return 0.0019 or 0.071 to the corresponding 'Result' field (Double). The values that have no prefix will remain as they are.

```
Prefix | Result | Result_Edit

..>.......0.07.......0.071

...........0.07.......0.07

..<.......0.07.......0.07

..<.......0.002......0.0019

...........0.002......0.002

..>.......0.002......0.002
```

I only care about <0.002 and >0.07.

This is what I have, but it doesn't work.....

```
def EDIT ( Prefix , Result , Result_Edit ):
  if (Prefix = '<' & Result = 0.002):
    return 0.0019
  elif (Prefix = '>' & Result =0.07):
    return  0.071
  else:
    return Result


EDIT ( !Prefix! , !Result! , !Result_Edit! )
```

Using ArcGIS Desktop v 10.5 with Python checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic of the code it's Ok, but you have some sintax errors. First of all, when executing this code it should give you a message telling that there was a failure and check the Results window, and there you can see that you have (at least) a sintax error in line 2.

Now, you have two sintax mistakes. First, you are using '=' to compare, but it is the assign operator. The compare operator is '==', at first is a bit confusing but you get used to it. The second mistake, is the '&' operator, this is used in other languages, but in python you should use 'and'. The final code will be this, and now it should run fine:

```
def EDIT ( Prefix , Result , Result_Edit ):
  if (Prefix == '<' and Result == 0.002):
    return 0.0019
  elif (Prefix == '>' and Result == 0.07):
    return  0.071
  else:
    return Result
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! Classic rookie mistake! Appreciate the help.

Comment: & is a binary AND; just like with the equals sign, you'd have to use && for it to work as expected, as in other languages. However python doesn't support that syntax at all.